# scikits.talkbox: ImportError: No module named cffilter

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikits

I'm trying to use the scikits.talkbox in python and I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named cffilter
```

I was looking for this file in the scikits.talkbox library and could only find 'cffilter.c' and 'cffilter.pyx' but not 'cffilter.py', it that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and resolved by installing `scikits.statsmodel`

```
pip install scikits.statsmodels
```

Indeed `cffilter` is mentioned in https://scikits.appspot.com/statsmodels.